# Unable to update listview/gridview after implementation of bloc technique

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

Hi I am unable to update my gridview, after adding new note to the database.

Just a little background, the adding of new note is working fine without the implementation of bloc. But after implementing it, i started facing the above problem, however with no error message shown.

Any help given is deeply appreciated!

My bloc provider class:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

abstract class BlocBase{
  void dispose();
}

class BlocProvider<T extends BlocBase> extends StatefulWidget{
  BlocProvider({
    Key key,
    @required this.child,
    @required this.bloc,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final T bloc;
  final Widget child;
  @override
  _BlocProviderState<T> createState() => _BlocProviderState<T>();

  static T of<T extends BlocBase>(BuildContext context){
    final type = _typeOf<BlocProvider<T>>();
    BlocProvider<T> provider = context.ancestorWidgetOfExactType(type);
    return provider.bloc;
  }

  static Type _typeOf<T>() => T;
}

class _BlocProviderState<T> extends State<BlocProvider<BlocBase>>{
  @override
  void dispose(){
    widget.bloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return widget.child;
  }
}
```

My bloc class:

```
class NotesBloc implements BlocBase{
  final _notesController = StreamController<List<Note>>.broadcast();

  StreamSink<List<Note>> get _inNotes => _notesController.sink;

  Stream<List<Note>> get notes => _notesController.stream;

  final _reminderController = StreamController<List<Note>>.broadcast();

  StreamSink<List<Note>> get _inReminderNotes => _reminderController.sink;

  Stream<List<Note>> get reminderNotes => _reminderController.stream;

  final _saveNoteController = StreamController<Note>.broadcast();
  StreamSink<Note> get inSaveNote => _saveNoteController.sink;
  final _deleteNoteController = StreamController<Note>.broadcast();
  StreamSink<Note> get inDeleteNote => _deleteNoteController.sink;

  final _noteDeletedController = StreamController<bool>.broadcast();
  StreamSink<bool> get _inDeleted => _noteDeletedController.sink;
  Stream<bool> get deleted => _noteDeletedController.stream;

  NotesBloc(){
    getNotes();
    getNotesReminder();
    _saveNoteController.stream.listen(_handleSaveNote);
    _deleteNoteController.stream.listen(_handleDeleteNote);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _notesController.close();
    _saveNoteController.close();
    _deleteNoteController.close();
    _noteDeletedController.close();
    _reminderController.close();
  }

  void getNotes() async{
    List<Note> notes = await DatabaseHelper.db.getNoteList();
    _inNotes.add(notes);
  }

  void _handleSaveNote(Note note) async {
    if (note.id == null) {
      await DatabaseHelper.db.insertNote(note);
      print('note added');
    } else {
      await DatabaseHelper.db.updateNote(note);
      print('note saved');
    }
    getNotes();
  }

  void _handleDeleteNote(Note note) async {
    await DatabaseHelper.db.deleteNote(note);
    _inDeleted.add(true);
    getNotes();
  }

  void getNotesReminder() async{
    List<Note> notes = await DatabaseHelper.db.getNoteListByReminderDate();
    _inReminderNotes.add(notes);
    getNotes();
  }
}
```

My submit method in editAddActivty:

```
void _submit() async {
    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      note.title = _titleController.text;
      note.bodyText = _bodyTextController.text;
      DateTime _date = DateTime.now();
      note.date = _date.toString();
      _noteBloc.inSaveNote.add(note);
      Navigator.of(context).pop();
      print('saved');
    }
  }
```

My Main Activity where it should show my newly added note, but didnt:

```
return StreamBuilder(
        // stream: reminder == reminderType.ForMain ? _notesBloc.notes : _notesBloc.reminderNotes,
        stream: _notesBloc.notes,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Note>> snapshot) {
          List<Note> noteList = snapshot.data;
          return Container(
              child: Padding(
            padding: _paddingForView(context),
            child: new StaggeredGridView.count(
              key: _stagKey,
              crossAxisSpacing: 6,
              mainAxisSpacing: 6,
              crossAxisCount: _colForStaggeredView(context),
              children: List.generate(snapshot.data?.length ?? 0, (i) {
                return MyStaggeredTile(noteList[i]);
              }),
              staggeredTiles: _tilesForView(noteList),
            ),
          ));
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement BLoC properly as recommended in Official documents. Then you can use BLoC listener.

What's issue un current code, you don't have any implemented listener. Go through https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterfirebaselogintutorial

Upper example is exact solution where you should to include Stream listener once update anything. Then you can update your object using streams.

Comment: Hihi, from my understanding from the link it uses flutter_bloc packages which uses a different approach to what i am doing now, which requeires (state, event and bloc class). While my approach is following this: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/using-streams-blocs-and-sqlite-in-flutter-2e59e1f7cdce/                                                                                How am i able to fix this problem without changing the whole structure of my code? As of the listener implementation. Under my NoteBloc constructor, it calls my streamcontroller to listen. Is that alright?